# Populate Combo box using LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to populate a combo box with data resulting from a LINQ query on a DataSet. The problem is, nothing is showing up in the combobox. At all.

```
var digits =
    (from digit in DDDataSet.Digits.AsEnumerable()
    where (!digit.pressed)
    select new {DigitList = digit.name});
cboDigits.DataSource = digits.ToList();
cboDigits.DisplayMember = "DigitList";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use databind is your digits returns values

Comment: Have you verified that the query actually returns at least one item (possibly through debugging)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to:

```
cboDigits.DataBind();
```

after you set the DataSource and DisplayMember.

Hope this helps

Comment: Im using WinForms. There's no need to call DataBind() i don't think

Comment: Very true. Maybe it's your linq. Have you tried like this:

var digits =
    (from digit in DDDataSet.Digits.AsEnumerable()
     where (!digit.pressed)
     select digit.name).ToList();
            cboDigits.DataSource = digits;

Without the anonymous type and DisplayMember?

Comment: Databind is not a member method

Answer (score 0):

Most controls do data binding automatically, which means that you typically do not need to call the method `DataBind` explicitly.

Linq when using `ToList()` won't be deferred, so all the data is computed. But, for `combobox`, it seems that you still need to use `DataBind()`.

If you are using `Winform`, you do not need `DataBind` to be called. If you are using Asp.Net you will need to.

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
    var stuff = dg.Stuffs.Where(c=> c.admin !=1).ToList();
                for (int i = 0; i < stuff.Count; i++)
                {
                    string test = stuff.ElementAt(i).Name;
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(test);

                }
```